# Collision Detection Cocos2d

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-x, side-scroller

My application is a sidescroller. I would like to be able to make my sprite be able to bump into an object and not be able to pass through it. I am very new to Cocos2d, so how can I make my character (sprite) do this?

Answer (score -1):

Start with the basics first, look and the tests project included in the cocosdx build

Have you read the tutorials on the cocos2dx wiki

http://www.cocos2d-x.org/projects/cocos2d-x/wiki/Chapter_5_-_How_to_Detect_the_Collisions

or look at ray wenderlich's site, really useful site for devs

http://www.raywenderlich.com/606/how-to-use-box2d-for-just-collision-detection-with-cocos2d-iphone

good luck